# Comparar fechas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una tabla llamada Entrada, la cual tiene estos parametros:

```
public function up(){
        Schema::create('entradas', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->date('fecha');
            $table->unsignedInteger('persona'); // Quien ha comprado la entrada.
            $table->foreign('persona')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Quiero hacer un formulario para crear una entrada, pero con la norma de que la fecha para la que se reserva no puede ser anterior a la actual.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

@Logged()
@include('partials.errors')
<div align="center" class="panel panel-default">
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Nueva reserva") }} </h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" action="../reserva">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fecha" class="col-md-12 control-label"> {{ __("Indique la fecha") }}
            </label>
            <input id="fecha" style="width:150px" type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" value="{{ old('fecha') }}"/>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="addPlanta" class="btn btn-default"> {{ __("Reservar entrada") }}
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
@else
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute" style="color:#FF0000"> {{ __("Debes haber iniciado sesión para crear una reserva") }} </h1>
@endLogged
@endsection
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('reserva','EntradaController@confirmar');
```

Y aqui donde se validara la reserva:

```
public function confirmar(Request $request){
        $normas=[
            'fecha' => 'required',
        ];

        $this->validate($request,$normas);

        if(Auth::user()->saldo<7)
            return back()->with('message', ['msg', __('No tienes suficiente dinero')]);
            else{
                $hoy=new DateTime("now");

                if($request->fecha>=$hoy){
                    $request->merge(['persona' => auth()->id()]);
                    Entrada::create($request->all());
                    Auth::user()->saldo-=7;
                    return back()->with('message', ['success', __('Reserva realizada con exito')]);
                }
                else
                    return back()->with('message', ['msg', __('No puede reservar para una fecha pasada')]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Y para mi sorpresa, independientemente de si la fecha elegida es mayor o menor que la actual siempre me sale el mensaje de error debido a que la fecha elegida es anterior a la actual.
Ya comprobe con dd() las variables de fechas y aunque la fecha actual da más información (horas, minutos, etc) que la fecha del formulario, estan ambas fechas.
¿Deberia quizas cambiar el formato de las fechas?

Edito: Ya logre que se realice la comparación, pero me topo con este mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He comprobado que sucede justo en el Entrada::create(). ¿Que fallara ahora?

Comment: ¿Qué formato está recibiendo el campo fecha?

Comment: @Shaz La fecha que se introduce en el formulario es Date, pero la fecha actual es una variable tipo DateTime.

Comment: No respondiste la pregunta, simplemente indica el formato de fecha que recibe la variable.

Comment: @Shaz si te refieres a el orden de los elementos de las fechas, el orden es año-minutos-segundos.

Comment: Sin meses ni días?

Comment: @Shaz Me he liado: año-mes-dia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel tiene un helper que entrega la fecha y hora actual, es `now()`, además Laravel utiliza Carbon, un wrapper muy potente y práctico de DateTime.

Tal vez lo más sencillo que puedes hacer es formatear el valor de now() para que entregue solo la fecha, la cual debería resultar en el mismo formato que entrega el campo tipo `date` de html (yyyy-mm-dd):

```
if ($request->fecha >= now()->toDateString()) ...
```

Por cierto, y más como sugerencia, en el método del controlador tienes un montón de lógica de validación, la cual estaría mejor ubicarla en un archivo independiente de validación de formularios: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation

Por último, y más por UX, si de antemano sabes que no le vas a permitir reservar al usuario por tener menos de "7" en su saldo, es mejor notificar al usuario antes de incluso llegar al formulario.

Comment: Gracias a tu codigo he logrado que se haga la comparación, pero ahora me he encontrado otro error. He editado mi comentario para explicar mi nuevo problema.

Comment: Eso es un problema distinto al que planteaste inicialmente, por lo cual te recomiendo aceptar esta respuesta y formular una nueva pregunta.

Comment: pues listo, ya he creado la nueva pregunta.